# How can I use the CSS selector to select a form when there are multiple forms on a page?

Tags: python, forms, beautifulsoup, mechanize-python, mechanicalsoup

I am trying to fill out a specific form on a webpage but the CSS selector I am using returns an error

I have tried these separately:

```py
 1. browser.select_form('form[method="post"]')
 2. browser.select_form()
 3. browser.select_form('form[action="/xxx"]')
```

But it either selects the search form at the top (no input) or returns the not found error:

in select_form raise LinkNotFoundError()
mechanicalsoup.utils.LinkNotFoundError

I expected it to select the correct form because this is the CSS of the form:

```
<form action="/xxx" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
```

EDIT:
When I look through the HTML of the webpage it doesnt have the form I am looking for. But when I inspect the elements of the webpage it is there. I assume this is the issue. Why and how is this happening and how can I use MechanicalSoup to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I cannot add a comment so pardon this answer.

But without looking at the page in question, I believe this might just be a case where the form is being inserted into the html through javascript on page load, therefore does not show up in raw html.

You might want to look into this

https://pythonprogramming.net/javascript-dynamic-scraping-parsing-beautiful-soup-tutorial/

https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/web-scraping-using-beautiful-soup-and-selenium-for-dynamic-page-2f8ad15efe25

Comment: I was thinking it would be something like this. Is there a way to access the form in Python after it has been built with javascript?

Comment: Looks like that might be a no with mechanicalsoup. "If the website relies on JavaScript, then you probably need a fully-fledged browser. Selenium may help you there, but it’s a far heavier solution than MechanicalSoup." 

https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html

Comment: Yes unfortunately it does seem like it can't be done without a simulated browser rendering the page. Perhaps someone with more experience working with dynamically rendered pages might guide you further.

Comment: You got it all right: MechanicalSoup won't help (unless you re-build the form by hand), as it doesn't interpret JS code.